# What struct can I use to decode a JSON array of arrays of strings?

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct, slice

I have the following JSON that I need do decode in Golang:

```
{
   "name":"test",
   "tags":[
      [
         "browser",
         "Chrome 28.0.1500"
      ],
      [
         "browser.name",
         "Chrome"
      ]
   ]
}
```

I came with some struct and some variations, but it still doesn't work:

```
type Response struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Tags map[int][]string `json:"tags"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WuVEHDLCS6H

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"tags"` is an array of arrays holding `string` values. So simply use a `[][]string` in Go to model it:

```
type Response struct {
    Name string     `json:"name"`
    Tags [][]string `json:"tags"`
}
```

After unmarshaling printing the `response`:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", response)
```

Output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UKT4U7pnJrV)):

```
{Name:test Tags:[[browser Chrome 28.0.1500] [browser.name Chrome]]}
```